# Saving list of Bitmaps to Parse.com | Android |

Tags: java, android, bitmap, parse-platform

I'm having a trouble saving an ArrayList to Parse.com data browser in android project

I have the following:

```
ArrayList<Bitmap> images = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
ParseObject po = new ParseObject("Test");
po.put("images", images);
po.saveInBackground();
```

Can anyone help me with that ??

Comment: try to test it by pass something other that `ArrayList<Bitmap>` like a regular `String`, and tell me if it works

Comment: @MuhammedRefaat yes its working well with Strings

Comment: [Maybe this answer can get you on the right track](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23939276/2791708).

Comment: @user3212556 look at my updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, regarding to your comment there are two possibilities:

*the first one* is that you fill that Bitmap ArrayList with Bitmaps which overloads your memory and causes that trouble.

*the second one* is that may be parse.com doesn't accept `ArrayLists` at all or doesn't accept `ArrayList<Bitmap>` as it doesn't include it in the examples of accepted Objects in the documentation, 
when taking a look at parse.com [docs](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseObject.html) you will find that put method doesn't accept `ArrayLists` as a `value`

```
public void put(String key,
                Object value)
```

Add a key-value pair to this object. It is recommended to name keys in partialCamelCaseLikeThis.

**Parameters:**

**key** - Keys must be alphanumerical plus underscore, and start with a letter.

**value** - Values may be numerical, String, JSONObject, JSONArray, JSONObject.NULL, or other ParseObjects. value may not be null.

**UPDATE**:

you can add it as an `Array<String>` that contains a Strings of converted `Bitmaps`, [this link](http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.com/2012/03/how-to-convert-string-to-bitmap-and.html) is how to convert a Bitmap to a String and vice-Versa

and if it doesn't accept `ArrayLists` at all you can put each `Bitmap` as a `String` individually

Comment: great idea,,I'm trying it
Thx alot