# How to upload spinner data on parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-spinner

I am new to android and parse.com.
I want to upload spinner selected data to parse.com and also I want to be updated at exact location how can I do that? Is there any Example of it ?

I haven't tried anything yet I do not know from where to start.

I am familiar with parse.com I have uploaded image and text data on it.
But I am stuck at spinner and searching for it from so long but I am not getting any help.

Thanks.

Comment: try this ans http://stackoverflow.com/a/16293203/3678308

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like as you upload a string data.

***Take a example here:***

```
Spinner mySpin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinid);
Button upload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.upload);

mySpin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,long id) {

     String myspinnerData = parent.getItemAtPostion(pos).toString();
}

upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {

ParseObject po = new ParseObject("TableName");
po.put("string",myspinnerData )
po.saveInBackground();

    }
});
```

Comment: I did it the same way long time ago. Anyways thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
Spinner sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
String sp_Value =   sp.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

when u want to change spinner value that a time use this default spinner method.

```
spCountry.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```