# Parse.com Signup with a Profile Picture and cover from a drawable

Tags: parse-platform, image-uploading

This is my **SignUp.class** I want to upload a profile picture drawable into User class in the **profilepic** column and a profile cover in the **profilecover** column

**R.drawable.avatar_circle** is the profile picture drawable and **R.drawable.drawer_header_light** is the drawable for the profile cover.

```
    package com.addict.secret;

    import android.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.app.Dialog;
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.CheckBox;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.parse.LogInCallback;
    import com.parse.ParseException;
    import com.parse.ParseGeoPoint;
    import com.parse.ParseUser;
    import com.parse.SignUpCallback;

    import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;


    public class SignUp extends AppCompatActivity {
        ProgressDialog login;
        ProgressDialog progress;
        EditText emailTxt, usernameTxt, passwordTxt, passwordConfirmTxt;
        Button registerBtn, termsBtn, aboutBtn;
        CheckBox mcheckbox;
        ParseUser User = new ParseUser();
        private Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
        overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.appBar_reset);
        toolbar.setTitle(R.string.title_activity_sign_up);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.icon_back_arrow);

        final FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fabprof);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(SignUp.this, R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle)
                        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_new_releases_black_24dp)
                        .setTitle(R.string.comingsoontitle)
                        .setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.comingsoon))
                        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
                        .create().show();
            }
        });

        //termsBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.termsBtn);
        //termsBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        //    @Override
        //    public void onClick(View v) {
        //        TermsDialogFragment dialog = TermsDialogFragment.newInstance();
        //        dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "DialogFragment");
        //    }
        //  });
        //aboutBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.aboutBtn);
        //aboutBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        //    @Override
        //    public void onClick(View v) {
        //        startActivity(new Intent(SignUp.this, About.class));
        //    }
        //  });
        emailTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        usernameTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Username);
        passwordTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        passwordConfirmTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordConfirm);
        registerBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.registerBtn);
        //Snackbar.make(context,getResources().getString(R.string.accept_notification);

        registerBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String email = emailTxt.getText().toString();
                String username = usernameTxt.getText().toString();
                String password = passwordTxt.getText().toString();
                String passwordConfirm = passwordConfirmTxt.getText().toString();

                Log.d("email", email);
                Log.d("username", username);
                Log.d("password", password);
                Log.d("password confirm", passwordConfirm);


                if (username.equals("")){
                    Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, R.string.signup_error_message_username, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if (email.equals("")){
                    Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, R.string.signup_error_message_email, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if (password.equals("") || password.length() < 6){
                    Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, R.string.signup_error_message_password6, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if (!passwordConfirm.equals(password)){
                    Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, R.string.signup_error_message_password, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else {
                    progress = new ProgressDialog(SignUp.this, R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle);
                    progress.setTitle(R.string.signup_dialog_title);
                    progress.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.signup_message));
                    progress.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                    progress.show();
                    registration(username, email, password);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void registration(final String username, String email, final String password){

        ParseGeoPoint currentLocation = new ParseGeoPoint(49.2827, -123.1207);;
        User.setUsername(username);
        User.put("status", getResources().getString(R.string.default_status));
        User.setEmail(email);
        User.setPassword(password);
        User.put("Location", currentLocation);
        User.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    progress.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, R.string.success_signup, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    signInUser(username, password);
                    SignUp.this.finish();
                } else {
                    progress.dismiss();
                    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(SignUp.this, R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle);
                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_error);


                    // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
                    TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.message);
                    text.setText(R.string.signup_error_parse);
                    ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
                    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.error_fox);

                    Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ok);
                    // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
                    dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });

                    dialog.show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void signInUser(String username, String password){
        login = new ProgressDialog(SignUp.this, R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle);
        login.setTitle(R.string.login_title);
        login.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.login_message));
        login.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        login.show();
        ParseUser.logInInBackground(username, password, new LogInCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseUser parseUser, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    login.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, R.string.success_login, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(SignUp.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, R.string.error_login, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
//        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_sign_up, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
//        int id = item.getItemId();
//
//        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
//        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
//            return true;
//        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should get the drawable and store it as a Bitmap:

```
Bitmap profilePic = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.avatar_circle);
Bitmap profileCover = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.drawer_header_light);
```

Then when you're signing up the user:

```
ParseGeoPoint currentLocation = new ParseGeoPoint(49.2827, -123.1207);;
User.setUsername(username);
User.put("status", getResources().getString(R.string.default_status));
User.setEmail(email);
User.setPassword(password);
User.put("profilepic", profilePic);
User.put("profilecover", profileCover);
User.put("Location", currentLocation);
```

Comment: The app **Crash**  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference

Comment: Shouldn't really be a problem. Just make sure that the reference to the drawables or to the string is correct.

Comment: Maybe I need to upload

Comment: Maybe I need to upload? You have any idea?

Comment: Sorry upload what? The error you got simply states that the program cannot find the file that you specified so it's probably the drawable's name or location.

Comment: Upload the drawable to parse server

Comment: Could do but this just seemed better to me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16292853/how-to-upload-an-image-in-parse-server-using-parse-api-in-android this method not functioning to me