# Uploading and retrieving image android studio Parse sever

Tags: java, android, android-studio, parse-platform

I'm trying to pick multiple images from users gallery and upload **(parse server)** this images to parse object then retrieve it and set it in an image view

and also i need to pick one image from gallery and save to the users profile

what i have already tried:

```
//Before OnCreate 
String da = "13412412412412414124ASDASDASDASDAD";
////After OnCreate
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        final Uri imageUri = data.getData();
        final InputStream imageStream;
        try {
            imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
            final Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
            String encodedImage = encodeImage(selectedImage);
            da=encodedImage;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private String encodeImage(Bitmap bm) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100,baos);
        byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
        String encImage = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return encImage;
    }
    private void ChooseImage() {
        Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);

    }
    private void CreateThing() {
        ParseObject thing = new ParseObject("Things");
        thing.put("Image",da);
        thing.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if (e==null)
                    Toast.makeText(class.this, "Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                else
                    Toast.makeText(class.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Please specify the problem you are facing with code (Behavior/exception)?

Comment: @Kryptonian null pointer exception , but I'm searching for a new full guide for uploading images to parse server

Comment: This might help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16292853/how-to-upload-an-image-in-parse-server-using-parse-api-in-android